# How can I simplify an *ngFor on a select

Tags: angular, select, dropdown, ngfor

Currently I can show the size of the household by getting the number of people using *ngFor and +1 for the correct selection; however this only gives me one option for selection and I need i + 10 for the amount of people

I have tried using *ngFor on option with no success

```
<label for="household_size">Household Size *</label>
      <select class="custom-select" id="household_size" formControlName="household_size">
             <option min="i + 1" *ngFor="let person of getPeoples(); let i = index" [value]="i + 1">{{i + 1}}</option>
             <option min="i + 2" *ngFor="let person of getPeoples(); let i = index" [value]="i + 2">{{i + 2}}</option>
             <option min="i + 3" *ngFor="let person of getPeoples(); let i = index" [value]="i + 3">{{i + 3}}</option>
             <option min="i + 4" *ngFor="let person of getPeoples(); let i = index" [value]="i + 4">{{i + 4}}</option>
             <option min="i + 5" *ngFor="let person of getPeoples(); let i = index" [value]="i + 5">{{i + 5}}</option>
             <option min="i + 6" *ngFor="let person of getPeoples(); let i = index" [value]="i + 6">{{i + 6}}</option>
             <option min="i + 7" *ngFor="let person of getPeoples(); let i = index" [value]="i + 7">{{i + 7}}</option>
             <option max="i + 8" *ngFor="let person of getPeoples(); let i = index" [value]="i + 8">{{i + 8}}</option>
             <option max="i + 9" *ngFor="let person of getPeoples(); let i = index" [value]="i + 9">{{i + 9}}</option>
             <option max="i + 10" *ngFor="let person of getPeoples(); let i = index" [value]="i + 10">{{i + 10}}</option>
             <option max="i + 11" *ngFor="let person of getPeoples(); let i = index" [value]="i + 11">{{i + 11}}</option>
      </select>
```

There should be a dropdown with 11 options 1, 2, 3 etc..

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to achieve. Could you please explain it? By giving  concrete example or two?

Comment: I am trying to dynamically get the amount of people selected and show this amount of people + 1 in the dropdown making the amount of dropdown options dynamic

Comment: what is the return value of `getPeoples()`

Comment: If `getPeoples()` returns 10 items, how many options do you expect in the `select` list?

Comment: Still really not clear to me. If there is no amount selected at all, what should the dropdown display as options? If the amount selected is 3, what should the dropdown display? If it's 10, what should the dropdown display? Where does the selected amount come from?

Comment: Another question: what are `min` and `max`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
         <select class="custom-select" id="household_size" formControlName="household_size">
            <option min="i + 1" *ngFor="let person of getPeoples(); let i = index" [value]="i + 1">{{i + 1}}</option>
          </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with this in the TS

```
householdSizeOptions = [];
  getAmountOfPeople(){
    this.householdSizeOptions = [];
      for (let i = this.getPeoples().length; i < this.getPeoples().length + 10; i++){
        this.householdSizeOptions.push(i);
      }
  }
```

And this in the HTML

```
<select class="custom-select" id="household_size" formControlName="household_size">
                <option *ngFor="let count of householdSizeOptions" [value]="count">{{count}}</option>
              </select>
```